# Анимация перехода цветов WPF не работает как надо

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, анимация, storyboard

Я хочу сделать индикацию, где цвета задаются пользовательскими свойствами зависимости. Реализацию описываю в xaml и столкнулся проблемой. 
 Реализация MainWindow.xaml

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <local:ConverterBrushToColor x:Key="BrushToColor"></local:ConverterBrushToColor>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(local:Animation.BrushColor0).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="animation">
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="{Binding BrushColor1, Converter={StaticResource BrushToColor}, ElementName=animation}"/>
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="Green"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <local:Animation x:Name="animation" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     Height="100" 
                     Margin="69.859,46.528,0,0" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                     Width="100" 
                     BrushColor1="Red"/>
</Grid>
```

Реализация Animation.xaml

```
    <Grid>
    <Label Background="{Binding BrushColor0, ElementName=User}"
           BorderBrush="Black" 
           BorderThickness="2">

    </Label> 
</Grid>
```

Обертка Animation.xaml.cs

```
    public class ConverterColorToBrush : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (null == value)
            return null;
        if (value is Color)
        {
            Color color = (Color)value;
            return new SolidColorBrush(color);
        }
        Type type = value.GetType();
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported type [" + type.Name + "]");
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ConverterBrushToColor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (null == value)
            return null;
        if (value is Brush)
        {
            Color color = (value as SolidColorBrush).Color;
            return color;
        }
        Type type = value.GetType();
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported type [" + type.Name + "]");
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public partial class Animation : UserControl
{
    public Animation() => InitializeComponent();

    public Color Color0
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(Color0Property); }
        set { SetValue(Color0Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Color0Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Color0", typeof(Color), typeof(Animation), new PropertyMetadata(Color.FromRgb(125,125,125)));

    public Color Color1
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(Color1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Color1Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Color1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Color1", typeof(Color), typeof(Animation), new PropertyMetadata(Color.FromRgb(125, 125, 125)));

    public Brush BrushColor0
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BrushColor0Property); }
        set { SetValue(BrushColor0Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BrushColor0Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BrushColor0", typeof(Brush), typeof(Animation), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Gray));

    public Brush BrushColor1
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BrushColor1Property); }
        set { SetValue(BrushColor1Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BrushColor1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BrushColor1", typeof(Brush), typeof(Animation), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Gray));
}
```

Я задаю цвет BrushColor1="Red" и хочу чтобы он через секунду поменял с  BrushColor0="Gray" на BrushColor1="Red". Проблема в том, что я получаю анимацию с серого цвета на прозрачный. Почему мой BrushColor1="Red" игнорируется и вместо него красится прозрачный цвет? Вот этот чать кода работает не так как я хочу

```
<DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="{Binding BrushColor1, Converter={StaticResource BrushToColor}, ElementName=animation}"/>
```

Из msdn, DiscreteColorKeyFrame.Value принимает только тип Color. Либо я неправильно конвертирую с Brush на Color, либо Binding в Value никаким образом не работает. Пробовал обратную конвертацию цвета сделать, когда Value передавал напрямую тип Brush и конвертировал в Color, но это тоже мне не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решается так:
Сперва нужно BrushColor0 определить не как Brush, а SolidColorBrush, а потом определить цвета в Resource таким образом:

```
 <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BrushColor0.Color, ElementName=User}" x:Key="BrushColor0"></SolidColorBrush>
 <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BrushColor1.Color, ElementName=User}" x:Key="BrushColor1"></SolidColorBrush>
```

а потом привязываться к DiscreteColorKeyFrame.Value

```
<DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource BrushColor0}}"/>
<DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource BrushColor1}}"/>
```